# Is there a trick to installing RMagick & ImageMagick on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rmagick

I keep getting Segmentation faults in the rmagick_processor.rb:52 (part of attachment_fu) while trying to run the test suite for community_engine on a fresh ruby app.

I've noticed I have both librmagick-ruby and librmagic-ruby1.8 which are both ImageMagick APIs for Ruby.  Should it be just one?  If so which?

Answer (score 1):

Further investigation revealed that the error was intermittent and after a few iterations I realized it was when I had a bunch of other apps on the go that the error would show up.  So for a change, instead of it being a coding error or install screw up on my part, it was a much more mundane segmentation fault - I was running out of memory.  Been a while since I have banged my head on that particular ceiling but it is a new Ubuntu install on an old laptop.

Answer (score 0):

This was a huge pain for me too. I ended up having to install libmagicwand to get everything to work happily. Could give this a shot - not sure if it will do you any good though. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

No, the '1.8' simply means that it is the build for Ruby 1.8, whereas the libmagick-ruby package depends on it to install it.  Once rebuilt for Ruby 1.9, 2.0, ... it will depend on those to bring them in.  So you need both.

If you have a bug report, you should probably try Ubuntu's launchpad not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Rmagick:  source, apt, or RubyGems?

Make sure you have only one copy of Ruby and RubyGems installed.

I personally like to install ruby & rubygems via apt... Then use **gem** to install things like RMagick.  Keeping RMagick up-to-date is as simple as "gem update rmagick".

On some platforms (CentOS 5.2), I have had to install specific versions of RMagick because the default repositories for my package manager (yum) only had old versions of the RMagick devel libraries.  I installed this version via:

```
gem install rmagick -v 1.15.13
```